# Postman Auto-Refresh Token Disabled

Tags: postman

I am trying to enable auto refresh for an Oauth token I use in a collection of calls in Postman. Whatever I do the toggle for auto-refresh is always disabled and has this message.

[image: postman error message]

I've tried refreshing the token multiple times. I also tried to setup a brand new collection with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share token URL?

Comment: Have same problem. Created new folder/collection and still have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the returned access_token is accompanied with the refresh_token for this feature to be enabled.

To get the refresh_token, you normally specify a scope "offline_access" in the scope parameter of authorization URL.